# Folder comparsion

Tags: batch-file, scripting, compare

I have two folders with sub folders. One folder is the base folder, and the other one is the local folder. In these folders and subfolders consist identical as well as non identical files.

I want compare these folders and report the result in some other file. This report must consist of:

1. List of all identical files
2. List of all modified files
3. List of any missing file or folder
4. List of all non identical file

Is there a tool, batch script or utility for this?

I have tried [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge), but it's not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

[BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is what you're looking for. It will give you all those reports in a matter of clicks.

**UPDATE**

As a follow up to your comment, you can also use this approach, which is as free as in beer, and does everything via command line.

Install a tool called [diff tools](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/difftool/difftool_bin.zip), and you'll be able to do something like:

diff.exe   
On the command line.

Comment: yeah but its licensed one any freeware in substitution of Beyond Compare

Is there any batch script we can write for this problem

Comment: Updated my post with another free option

Comment: @WENzER - didn't you ask about batch scripts previously? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415678/comparing-folders-and-subfolders-files-using-batch-command And in this current question you explicitly state that you want to know about any utility?

Answer (score 1):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/) is very good for this. I comes in a 64 bit version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have to recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for this, it's an **excellent** folder and file comparison tool.  You can [integrate it into Visual Studio](http://preetsangha.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-beyond-compare-with-visual-studio.html) as well for the file comaprison for a **much** better merging experience as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WinDiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff), a graphical file-comparison program.